# g8 prompts do not show in msysgit bash

Tags: scala, msysgit, giter8

I'm trying to use g8 to generate scala probjects, but under the msysgit bash shell, it does not show the usual prompts, such as organization, etc. The below is the expected output:

```
>> g8 typesafehub/akka-scala-sbt

Akka 2.0 Project Using Scala and sbt

organization [org.example]: akka.tutorial
package [org.example]: akka.tutorial.first.scala
name [Akka Project In Scala]:
akka_version [2.0]:
version [0.1-SNAPSHOT]:

Applied typesafehub/akka-scala-sbt.g8 in akka-project-in-scala
```

I do it get this mac and using the Windows cmd.exe console. But under msysgit, it prints out the `Akka 2.0 Project Using Scala and sbt` and then nothing else, so it looks like it hangs. However it i type in the expected values and hit return it works as expected. The prompts are just not printed to the screen.

Any suggestion on how to get this working properl, since i really would prefer not to resort to cmd.exe

Comment: I'm having the same strange problem under Windows 8... did you ever get an answer?